# How to change content of page from input "forever"? (create primitive blog)

Tags: javascript, php

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text');
var previousText;

function send() {
 previousText = document.getElementById('text-place').innerHTML;
 document.getElementById('text-place').innerHTML = text.value + "<br><br>" + previousText;
    document.getElementById('text').value = "";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <input type="text" name="enter" class="enter" placeholder="Your text..."    value="" id="text" />
 <button onclick="send();" id="button">Send</button>
  <p id="text-place"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Hello, I need your help about one thing. I would like to create a primitive blog, but I can not figure out how to take value from the input of a "forever" be written to the tag

so see it anyone, who comes to the site. I tried to search and I found only cookies in PHP. I have this JavaScript code, but I find out, that it's impossible. Does anyone here how to do it?Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to write entries to database to persist changes. Use PDO for database interactions, also check MySql (both in PHP side). Send information from JS using Ajax. Too broad for SO to answer.